# Pinescript strategy is not printing correctly on charts (possible timestamp problem)

Tags: timestamp, pine-script

I was trying to backtest a Strategy that relies on Depth of Market (DOM) data.

Unfortunatley that data can't be accessed in Pinescript, nor can I access by calling an API (please correct me if wrong!)...

So instead I am trying to hardcode the values into my script as per this FAQ: https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-initialize-a-series-on-specific-dates-using-external-data

I'm playing around with a modified version of the code taken from the above link, but I can't get it to display correctly.

**What I expect to happen:** I thought it would print 5 single dots at 1am, 2am, 3am, 4am, and 5am on the 5th of May. Each dot would be 1 step higher than the next.

**What happens instead:** It prints 24 dots, one for each hour of the 5th of May. All the dots are in the same level, there is no stepping.

Here is the code I am using:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Initialize External Data")

// Dates must appear in chronological order and match chart dates.
// The limit of lines is ~900. Variables used in your calcs will decrease this amount.
float data = na
timestamp = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, 0, 0, 0)
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 0, 0, 0) ? 1 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 1, 0, 0) ? 2 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 2, 0, 0) ? 3 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 3, 0, 0) ? 4 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 4, 0, 0) ? 5 : data

plot(data, "data", color.fuchsia, 2, plot.style_circles)
```

And here is a screenshot of what I am seeing on my chart (1hr chart with timezone set as "exchange"):

[image]

Can anyone describe what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `timestamp` has no `hour` variable, so it's always fixed at May 1st, 00:00h.
That only matches your first line, so the output will always be `1`.

This will work:

```
//@version=4
strategy("Initialize External Data")

// Dates must appear in chronological order and match chart dates.
// The limit of lines is ~900. Variables used in your calcs will decrease this amount.
float data = na

timestamp = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, 0, 0)

data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 0, 0, 0) ? 1 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 1, 0, 0) ? 2 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 2, 0, 0) ? 3 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 3, 0, 0) ? 4 : data
data := timestamp == timestamp(2021, 05, 01, 4, 0, 0) ? 5 : data

plot(data, "data", color.fuchsia, 2, plot.style_circles)
```

which yields:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I thought the mutable timestamp variables would be updated on each line regardless of how the `timestamp` variable was declared. I don't fully understand why it needs to be declared with the built-in variable first for it to work, but it does works nonetheless :)

Comment: That's because your script is [executed at every bar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html). So on each bar, your `timestamp` variable will be re-calculated and compared to the fixed timestamps in your comparison list.

Comment: I'm a self taught coder so sometimes I don't correctly think through pieces of code that I find online. This is one of those of those times. I now see that `data` is the mutable variable, not `timestamp`. `timestamp` is simply used as a comparison in the ternary, and it could never match the current current timestamp because I hardcoded those hr/min/sec parts to be 0.